# Email sent from web server using PHP does not arrive

Tags: opensuse, email, php

I am trying to send email via my web server using PHP but for some reason the email never arrives. According to PHP the email was sucessfully sent but I never receive the email. I know its not a spam problem as the web server used to be able to successfully send email until I reinstalled it last week. It has been installed with exactly the same OS and configuration except now it doesn't work.

It is using the default PHP settings for sending email and I have enabled SMTP in the firewall but this doesn't seem to be working.

Are there any logs for the PHP email sending that may be able to help me trouble shoot why it isn't working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP is probably trying to talk to a local SMTP server, that is, one running on the same machine as the web server. So, have you set one up? There are many to choose from. The most popular are Sendmail, Exim, Postfix, and Qmail.

Try sending email using the primitive `mailx` client. If it can't send mail outside the machine, it's probably for the same reason PHP can't, so the problem would therefore lie outside PHP.

Try sending email by hand from the command line by `telnet`ting to `localhost` on port 25 and speaking the SMTP by hand. There are many guides for this online. [Here's one](http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/smtp.shtml). Where you go from there depends on what happened:

- If you get no answer on port 25, there is no SMTP server running.
- If it answers, maybe it will give an error message that clues you in to the problem.
- If it appears to accept the email, you have to go about debugging your local SMTP server.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've tried sending the email via telnet and when I send the message it displays the message `250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6B32C28B7D` does this mean it thinks it has worked or is the server just queing and not actually sending. If it is queing what would make it not send. Thanks for your help

Comment: you should check the mail queue to see if it has actually set... but doing that depends a lot on your mail server. Also you should check your mail logs.

Comment: I've now tried reinstalling the server and I get the same message when I send the mail through telnet. I then run mailq to view the queue and it says mail queue is empty

Comment: @Boardy: Then xenoterracide is right: you should check your mail server's logs.

Comment: Is there any particular logs, sorry I'm fairly new to linux

Comment: @Boardy: Which email server are you using?

Comment: Its postfix on opensuse 11.2

Comment: According to the [Postfix Debugging Howto](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html) the logs will go to `/var/log/mail` or `/var/log/maillog`. The rest of the Howto will probably also be helpful to you as you chase this problem.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, looking at the log and doing a tcpdump I could see that the email was being sent as it was reading my MX record and knowing it was going to gmail. I then realised that for some reason gmail is seeing that the address I normally use for sending emails from my server is now spam and has put them all in the junk folder. Feel like a bit a moron now. Thanks for your help though

Comment: @Boardy: That means your mail server may have been compromised. Check that it isn't an open relay. You might also do a check for root kits, especially if you don't keep your system patched up to date. Google doesn't blacklist someone's mail server for no cause at all.